# Password is not allowed nodejs + mongo db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am creating a web api with node js and mongodb.
i have tried to create a route and when i check it with the postman it says

**"password" is not allowed**

Here is the code I have Used

for the route

```
router.post('/adminregister', upload.single('profileImage'), async(req, res) => {

const { error } = registerValidation(req.body);
if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
if (emailExists) return res.status(400).send('Email Already Exists');

const user = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    gender: req.body.gender,
    bday: req.body.bday,
    email: req.body.email,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    image: req.file.path,
    password: req.body.password
});
try {
    const savedUser = await user.save();

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET);

    res.header('auth-token', token).send({
        loginstatus: 'olduser',
        token: token
    });
} catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send(err);
}});
```

This is the user Schema

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 5
},
gender: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
bday: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 255,
    min: 6
},
phone: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 6
},
image: {
    type: String
        // required:true
},
password: {
    type: String
},
usertype: {
    type: String,
    default: 'user'
},
status: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: 'active'
}});
```

**When I do a request though postman it gives me this**

but when I remove the password from postman it works fine

[image]

Comment: Post the code for `registerValidation`

Comment: are you using joi validation ?

Comment: yes @SaurabhMistry but I did not write code to validate password `const registerValidation = data => {
    const schema = {
        name: Joi.string().min(6).required(),
        gender: Joi.required(),
        bday: Joi.required(),
        email: Joi.string().min(4).email(),
        phone: Joi.string().min(5)    }

    return Joi.validate(data, schema);}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to allow any other key in Joi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49897639/how-to-allow-any-other-key-in-joi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `joi` if you haven't added `password`, it will not allow it. You need pass options

```
options: {
    allowUnknown: true
  }
```

to make it work while calling `Joi.validate` method.

Answer (score 2):

add `unknown(true)` to your Joi schema , to allow other keywords in request body

```
validationSchema:Joi.object().keys({ 
    name: Joi.string().required(), 
    ... 
}).unknown(true)
```